# PHP curl error: ssl peer certificate or ssh remote key was not ok

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I am having some issues communicating to certain third party system, through CURL in PHP.

This is part of the code I have to submit come requests

```
$query = '<tag>some xml content with request data</tag>';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://secure.certainsystem.com/function.php");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

The request is the same for all cases, **but sometimes** I don't get any data from the `curl_exec($ch)`, and instead, when I run `curl_error($ch)`, I get:

> SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

This is not happening all the times, but it is happening, so I'm not sure what the problem could be, if the problem is in the code, or there is a problem in the third party system I'm comunicating to.

I searched for this message error in other places and here as well, and I found that if `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is set to `true`, then it could be a problem with the third party system's certificate, perhaps a self-signed one. But in my case, that option is set to `0`, which I assume is taken as `false`.

Recently I found there is an option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`, but I'm not setting that option to any value, so I think it is taking the default, which according to PHP.net documentation, is `2`, which means:

> 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false instead of 0?

Comment: I just tried setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false`, it seems to be ok for now. As this error happens almost randomly, I'll have to wait and see it this works.

Answer (score 1):

add options

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

more see here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/171188

Answer (score 0):

Although I am answering an old post, I think it will help the new viewers-

You can check the problem by adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

The reason is explained in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673024/1485809).